# Navigation menu changes with smaller windows?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

You can view the page I'm talking about here:

http://portal.escalateinternet.com/test.php

The black navigation menu appears to become mobile friendly whenever you make the browser window smaller.  I'm not sure if this is CSS, Javascript, PHP, or HTML related and feel like I've looked everywhere for the fix but can't seem to figure it out.

Is there anything I can change in the CSS or HTML to stop this from happening?  I want it to appear the same regardless of how big the browser window is.

Comment: It seems to be switching to the mobile version of the nav bar anytime the active window width is less than 960px. The css being activated there is line 877 of `flex.css`

Comment: Made it an answer so people will easily know how to solve this issue if the have a similar problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be switching to the mobile version of the nav bar anytime the active window width is less than 960px. The css being activated there is line 877 of `flex.css`:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 960px) {

.whmcscontainer {
 margin-left: 20px;
 margin-right: 20px;
}
```

Can either change that 960 or just get rid of it entirely depending on your needs.